# CSP error when embed a website with facebook chat widget into another website

Tags: iframe, facebook-javascript-sdk, content-security-policy, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-chat

I have implemented the [Facebook chat plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/facebook-chat-plugin) into my website, and it works great.
However, a CSP error is raised when I tried to embed the website into another website of a different domain

> Refused to frame 'https://www.facebook.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors https://example.com".

Any input on how to embed the website as the iframe into other websites would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you added that top-level site as a whitelisted domain in your app settings?

Comment: Yes, I did whitelist the top-level site as well :)